# MyBatis committing a statement even when autocommit is false

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis

I've been using myBatis 3.2.8 with C3p0 as the data source. Recently I ran into some odd problem.
Basically, myBatis is committing my INSERT statement even when auto commit is explicitly passed as FALSE and session.commit() isn't even called.
Here's what my code block looks like:

```
SqlSession session = factory.openSession(false);
try {
  mapper.insert(myObject);
  doStuff();
  session.commit();
}
catch (Throwable t)
{
  session.rollback();
  // log exception
}
finally {
  session.close();
}
```

Basically what I observed was, when mapper.insert(myObject) was called, the data was immediately stored to my database, as I was stepping throught this statement in my debugger, and I saw those logs:

```
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:34,730] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: decremented pending_acquires: 0
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:34,730] org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction: Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@33dbc40]
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:34,773] com.liangzhi.core.api.database.mapper.ProjectMapper.insertProject: ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO projects (ProjectName, ProjectAbstractText, ProjectFairID) VALUES (?, ?, ?); 
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:34,975] com.liangzhi.core.api.database.mapper.ProjectMapper.insertProject: ==> Parameters: 3568bca0-2bc2-4610-b6f1-a6858752817c(String), 3568bca0-2bc2-4610-b6f1-a6858752817c(String), 1(Integer)
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:35,018] com.liangzhi.core.api.database.mapper.ProjectMapper.insertProject: <==    Updates: 1
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:35,018] org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction: Committing JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@33dbc40]
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:35,168] org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction: Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@33dbc40]
DEBUG [2014-10-27 05:30:35,170] org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction: Closing JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@33dbc40]
```

I'm confused because I haven't called close connection yet and it's already closing JDBC connection.
Note that "false" is passed for factory.openSession() to disable autoCommit.

This is my myBatis config:

```
<environments default="dev">
        <environment id="dev">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC">
                <property name="JDBC.autoCommit" value="false" />  
            </transactionManager>
            <dataSource type="com.liangzhi.core.api.database.C3P0DataSourceFactory">
                <property name="driverClass" value="${dev.driver}" />
                <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dev.url}" />
                <property name="user" value="${dev.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${dev.password}" />
                <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
                <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
                <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600"/>
                <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>  
                <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
```

and this is my datasource class

```
public class C3P0DataSourceFactory extends UnpooledDataSourceFactory {

  public C3P0DataSourceFactory() {
    this.dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
  }
}
```

Please help me! Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure it was actually committed to the database?  Check using another connection to the same database.  I think you might misunderstand how commit works : it doesn't queue all the changes you made to the db and execute them at once (those changes get executed as you execute them), it essentially just notes in the transaction log that they really occurred.